# Titanium: Why don't the animation apply to view children?

Tags: ios, titanium

In a Titanium project, i am using the following code for drag and drop of an image view

```
Utils.prototype.makeDraggable = function(view, onDropped) {
    var olt = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix(), curX=0, curY=0, endX=0, endY=0;
    var animation_in_progress = false;

    view.setTransform(olt);

    view.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        curX = e.x; curY = e.y;
    });

    view.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        // update the co-ordinates based on movement since last movement or touch start
        var deltaX = e.x - curX, deltaY = e.y - curY;

        if (!animation_in_progress) {
            olt = olt.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
            animation_in_progress = true;
            view.animate({
                transform : olt,
                duration : 50,
                curve: Titanium.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
            }, function(e) {
                animation_in_progress = false;
            });
        }
    });

    view.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        if (onDropped) {
            onDropped(e);
        }
    });
}
```

It works ok on a single ImageView.

Now I want to drag and drop a group of ImageView. My idea is to create a parent view, add the image views to this parent and then to animate the parent view.

Unfortunately, as soon as I add children to a view, this one can not animated anymore.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?
What would be your recommendations for implementing drag and drop on a group of views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing that your children views are interfering with your touch events.  One thing to try  would be to set `touchEnabled` to false for every child view, then apply the `makeDraggable` method to your parent view.